# InvalidPipeArgument: 'Missing locale data for the locale "pt-BR".' for pipe 'xl' environment prod Angular

Tags: angular, pipe, angular-cli, angular8

I made a pipe to display monetary value in the Brazilian format. When squeegee everything works normally. However when running in a DEV / Prod environment on azure I get this message. The error also happens when it runs `"ng serves --prod"`.

This is configuration in the module

```js
import { LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import localePt from '@angular/common/locales/pt';


registerLocaleData(localePt);


  providers: [
    {
      provide: LOCALE_ID,
      useValue: 'pt-PT'
    }
  ],
```

PIPE AS HTML

```html
 {{produto.valorAntesPromocao | number:'1.2-2'}}
```

Error message :

> InvalidPipeArgument: 'Missing locale data for the locale "pt-BR".' for
> pipe 'xl'

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Can you try adding [this](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20197) way

```
import { LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import localePt from '@angular/common/locales/pt';

registerLocaleData(localePt);

@NgModule({
      providers: [
        { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'pt-BR' }    
      ]  
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 7):

Try in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59204742/5898385) way:-

```
import {LOCALE_ID} from '@angular/core';
import localePt from '@angular/common/locales/pt';
import {registerLocaleData} from '@angular/common';

registerLocaleData(localePt, 'pt');

@NgModule({
    providers: [
        {
            provide: LOCALE_ID,
            useValue: 'pt'
        }
    ]
})
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I've solved this problem:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { PostComponent } from './post/post.component';
//**************** imports here ****************
import { DEFAULT_CURRENCY_CODE, LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core';
import ptBr from '@angular/common/locales/pt';
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
// registerlocaledata
registerLocaleData(ptBr);
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, PostComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule],
//configuring providers.
  providers: [
    {
      provide: LOCALE_ID,
      useValue: 'pt',
    },
    {
      provide: DEFAULT_CURRENCY_CODE,
      useValue: 'BRL',
    },
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use "pt" as provider value:

```
{
    provide: LOCALE_ID,
    useValue: 'pt'
}
```

According this [thread on github](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20197#issuecomment-341961683), Angular uses "pt" for brazilian formats and "pt-pt" for the european portuguese.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { DEFAULT_CURRENCY_CODE, LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core';
import ptBr from '@angular/common/locales/pt';
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
    
registerLocaleData(ptBr);
    
providers: [
    {
    provide: LOCALE_ID,
    useValue: 'pt',
    },
    {
    provide: DEFAULT_CURRENCY_CODE,
    useValue: 'BRL',
    },
],
```

Isto Funcionou Perfeitamente para mim, Creditos ao nosso amigo @MarcosVidal

This Worked Perfectly for me, Credits to our friend @MarcosVidal

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33942345)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).